# Find all the Controllers and Models a route calls in rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

Is there any way to find all the controllers, models and helpers a route is touching? I tried this, which is logging all the method calls for each and every basic operation but I just want to know the controllers and models and helpers which are used.

```
set_trace_func proc { |event, file, line, id, binding, classname|
  printf "%8s %s:%-2d %10s %8s\n", event, file, line, id, classname
}
```

Comment: Something like https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Kernel.html#method-i-caller ?

Comment: But I don't know what all functions are getting called to put the caller inside the function. But anyway it was a nice read. Thanks @OneNeptune

Comment: What I do normally is check the log file for all the partial and views rendered and check what all files are included in the model or view or controller and do step by step debugging by using go to function.